# Can I deprecate a const?

Tags: php

In [PHP Doc](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.deprecated.pkg.html), we can read this about `@deprecated` tag :

> The @deprecated tag is used to document the deprecation version or other information of any element that can be documented except for page (global variable, include, constant, function, define, class, variable, method). If present, phpDocumentor will display the optional version/info string unaltered.

I need to deprecate a constant so that a warning is displayed when it is used. It seems that this can be done with this tag.
Is the following syntax correct?

```
/**
 * @deprecated 
 */
 define('FOO', 'value');
```

Comment: It seems right. As the docs say it works on every "global variable, include, constant, function, define, class, variable, method" I don't think there's any problem in this.

Comment: Try is and tell us if you get the deprecation message

Comment: Seems to work in VSCode.

Comment: Yes, it's working on VSCode (the const is crossed out), but no warning displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it in PHP Storm, and it detects it. It depends on IDE, some might not support it. Works with `const` syntax too:

```php
/**
 * @deprecated use BOWER_COMPONENTS instead
 */
const YII_BOWER_COMPONENTS = BOWER_COMPONENTS;
echo YII_BOWER_COMPONENTS;
```

[image]